# Want to unbind dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I had created web application in that i want to use two dropdownlist.when i select some value from dropdown1 it affect dropdown2 but the value bind first time not get clear can any one please help me

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Select sel_obj = new Select();
        #region Load Department Name
        if (departchk.Checked==true && DropDownList1.SelectedIndex==1)
        {

            DataTable DT = sel_obj.select_Dept_Name();
            recordddl.DataSource = DT;
            recordddl.DataTextField = "Department_Name";
            //departmentDrop.DataValueField = "Department_ID";
            recordddl.DataBind();
            recordddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
        #endregion
        #region Load Employee Name
        else if(departchk.Checked==true && DropDownList1.SelectedIndex==2)
        {

            DataTable DS = sel_obj.select_Emp_Name();
            recordddl.DataSource = DS;
            recordddl.DataTextField = "Employee_Name";
            recordddl.DataBind();
            recordddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
        #endregion
        #region Load Location Name
        else if(departchk.Checked==true && DropDownList1.SelectedIndex==3)
        {
            DataTable DD2 = sel_obj.select_Location_Name();
            recordddl.DataSource = DD2;
            recordddl.DataTextField = "Location_Name";
            recordddl.DataBind();
            recordddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: I am try  recordddl.Items.Clear(); recordddl.DataSource = null; for unbind but it's not unbind

Comment: When is what value supposed to be cleared?

Comment: We need more of your code. At what point is recordddl supposed to be cleared?

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as `DropDownList1.Items.Clear();`

[Check a complete example here](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-remove-all-items-from.html)

Comment: Still having problems , then update your code with complete page's code and markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can "unbind" a drop down by setting the DataSource to null, then calling DataBind.

Comment: recordddl.DataSource = null;
 recordddl.DataBind(); but nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in SharePoint 2013 (using .NET 4.5), and found I had to set all these

```
ddl.Items.Clear();
ddl.SelectedIndex = -1;
ddl.SelectedValue = null;
```

before I was able to do this to rebind my ddl

```
ddl.DataSource = list;
ddl.DataTextField = displayField;
ddl.DataValueField = valueField;
ddl.DataBind();
```

without getting the error 'ddl has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items...'

Answer (score 0):

Write this before  binding.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: DropDownList.Items.Clear(); unable to unbind data

Comment: you can try this. dropdownlist1.datasource = null;
dropdownlist1.databind()

Comment: also check its not getting bind from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things

dropdown list should be `runat='server'`

1. you want reset the `selectedindex =0.`
2. Clear the collection items from dropdownlist
   then use `dropdownlist.items.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcustomer" runat ="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcustomer_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack ="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

When you will unbind your DropdownList then simply assign

```
if (ddCountryName.SelectedItem != null)
    LoadDivisionStateName();
else
    ddDivisionStateName.Items.Clear();
```